# How can i make website startup audio mobile friendly?

Tags: html, audio, web, startup

As of now I am using the  tag in html to make audio play although this doesn't seem to work on android or ios.

Comment: try with Audio Bootstrapping

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using JavaScript, but have you tried an 'onload' attribute?

HTML

```
<body onload='myOnload()'>
etc etc
```

JavaScript

```
function myOnload() {
   var myAudio = new Audio(//insert source)
   myAudio.play()
}
```